# Render dropdown as text for particular action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that I use for editing and creating my models.  When a user is editing the model, I would like a particular drop-down to be rendered as text as I don't want them to change it.  A read-only drop-down would suffice, but I'd prefer text.

I'm thinking I can accomplish this via an extension method, but I'm not quite sure how to get started.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to drop down the list, or do you just want the currently-selected display value to be shown in the view?

Comment: The latter.  See my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I tried (and it works) - though I'm not a fan of if/else's in my views :)

```
<% if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.Equals("Edit"))
       { %>
    <span><%= Event.Retailer.Name%></span>
    <%= Html.Hidden("Retailer", Event.Retailer.Id) %>
    <%}
       else
       { %>
    <%=Html.DropDownList("Retailer", Model.Retailers, "Select", new { @class = "field select large required" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Retailer", "*")%>
    <%} %>
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing now. If you are using the same view for both creating and editing records, an `if` statement is unavoidable, as you need a way to *change the state of the view.* I generally just use two different views for `create` and `edit`.

Comment: Yea - I read somewhere that if you need an "if" statement - use a helper.  I could do Html.Retailer(..) I suppose.  I'd use a different view for `create` and `edit`, but the forms are so similar, I was able to group them